# Geocode 250,000 addresses quickly

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am starting to use the Google Maps Javascript API, and found that to place markers on the map, I must use coordinates instead of addresses.

To convert the addresses to coordinates, one must run the addresses through a geocoder. I have 250,000+ addresses in a database that I need geocoded very soon, and Google's geocoder has a limit of 2500 a day and takes over an hour just to geocode 1000 addresses.

So my question... How do I process all the addresses and store the coords in a MySQL database?

Comment: You're going to find that almost no service will allow you to do more than that in a batch unless you're willing to pay for it.  It's actually very expensive and server intensive for the servers to provide that information.  You should consider yourself lucky to get the 2500 a day for free.  Sorry...  But that's what my research has told me...

Comment: I'm willing to pay for it, I'm just looking for an API that can process all the addresses, like, yesterday...

Comment: In that case, go to this site:  http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/  It uses a Bing API developer key, which you can create yourself.  And they offer a subscription based service that will allow you to batch gazillions of stuff.  All the information is there.

Comment: Which country do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday? That's not happening unless you have one of those hopped up Delorean cars from Back to the Future.

A few years back I signed up for a commercial Google Maps license; it was US$10K per year back then. It was expensive but worked fast and well. It took a few days to make the deal as I recall. We did get a big batch of stuff done in a day or two once it was all debugged.

It's possible to download the openstreetmap.org software and data, implement it on a server you own, and hammer away at it to geocode your quarter megarow of places.

This will take a while and some equipment.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the result of the query and simply wait until everything is geocoded.